# What data type is the word/number "3A" in SQL

Tags: sql, database, integer, mariadb, varchar

I am using a database to store my data in a tabels. I want to make a column with class 3A as data value. What data type is the value 3A? Is this INT or VARCHAR or none of these?

Answer (score 0):

`3A` is a string.  A number is something you can perform arithmetic operations on.  I don't see how `3A` can be involved with addition or division or the like.

Comment: Since the question was string or number: how about 0x3A (which would imply that all names are hexadecimal numbers)

Comment: @GeorgRichter . . . Most databases, MariaDB included, don't have really good support for hexadecimal values.  That said, if the OP does want binary, then a binary blob would work.

Comment: So this values 3A is probably a STRING but it could also be a hexadecimal number.